# Angular 12 - Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular

This was asked years ago and I don't know if the answer has changed as I am on Angular 12. The answer seems to be two-fold and is caused but one of two scenarios. Either the app.module.ts does not have FormsControl in the imports section or there are multiple modules. I do have the FormsControl in my root file (app.module.ts) and I also only have one module. When I take the ngModel out of the input statement, it works fine. I am getting this using the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dpv6lUKNL9o where it seems to work fine and has the FormsControl set up correctly.

I also tried adding the FormsModule to the page the input was on and it gave me a duplicate ta
Is there anything else that would cause this?

html file:

[image]

app.module.ts

[image]

The parens instead of the brackets works much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[{ngModel}]` on the input tag

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="DepartmentName" />
```